# How to show git commit stats?

Tags: git

I would like `git commit` to have an output similar to `git merge` (or `git diff --stat`).

`git merge` prints some stats with the format:

```
<path_to_file> | <number_of_edition> +++++-----
```

and `git commit` prints something like:

```
[<branch> <hash>] <message>
 3 files changed, 9 insertions(+), 10 deletions(-)
```

How can I have the output from `git merge` (or `git diff --stat`) in the output of `git commit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write your own script for that.
You can use hooks to echo your commit info as you want it.

The hook can be `pre-commit` hook.
In your hooks you can simple echo `git diff --stat`

#### Commit hooks flow:

```
    pre-commit
        v
prepare-commit-msg
        v
   commit-msg
        v
  post commit
```

More about hooks can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).